# How to find out which math departments have a research group in mathematical logic?

Tags: phd, mathematics

I'm thinking to apply to PhD programs in math. I want to study mathematical logic. So I need programs that have mathematicians who do research in this area. I've searched the internet, the results were not satisfactory. The only list I've found find is [this one](http://grad-schools.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/logic-rankings)

But this list contains only 9 schools (which are very difficult to get into!). I was wondering if anybody can guide me to some longer lists of schools and PhD programs that have expert(s) in mathematical logic?

Comment: I recommend browsing issues of the Journal of Symbolic Logic and looking up where authors are from.

Comment: Hopefully, some logician will come along and make some suggestions;  this is something where ultimately, talking to someone is the best plan.  That said, there's a reason that the US News list is so much shorter for logic than for core disciplines.  There really are just a lot fewer programs in it.

Comment: Jean Larson's list of set theorists (with school information): http://www.math.ufl.edu/~jal/set_theory.html Peter Cholak's list of computably theorists: http://www3.nd.edu/~cholak/computability/computability.html

Comment: Look for potential advisors, not PhD programs.

Comment: Berkeley has a Ph.D. in logic: http://logic.berkeley.edu/

Answer (score 13):

I guess some logician is me. I don't know of any list of schools that have programs in logic, and it would be hard to keep such a list anywhere close to comprehensive---very few schools have more than one or two people in mathematical logic, so the list would change frequently based on whose hired/moved/retired recently.

Steffen Lempp keeps a [list of logicians](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~lempp/main.html#other) which, while not comprehensive, is pretty large, so the institutions those people are at is a good place to start.  Another idea is looking at whose spoke at recent logic conferences (for instance, the program for [this year's](http://www.aslonline.org/files/AnnualMeeting2013Program.pdf) ASL annual meeting, or the European equivalent, the Logic Colloquium).

Always, of course, if you know any faculty who are familiar with your interests (not necessarily logicians themselves), they may be able to point you towards some schools.

Also, note that there's no school with anything like a "generic" logic program---anywhere you go, your specialization within the field will be limited by whose present there. You likely have some narrower idea than generic logic that you're most interested in, so looking for people working in that area (or who've done work you think is interesting) is a good way to find schools. (You shouldn't obsess about this, though; you don't have to work in exactly the same area as your advisor anyway, and your interests are likely to shift at least a little over time.)

Comment: Although, Berkeley appears to have a strong logic subgroup of the math department.

Comment: Berkeley also has an actual separate logic track within its graduate program, with different qualifying exams etc.  I don't know of anywhere else with a comparable set up (though it seems CMU has something similar).  Obviously if you can get into Berkeley or CMU (and you want to study logic), you should go.  The OP pointed out that one might rightly want a backup plan.